# How to implement progressbar using AsyncTask in list fragment?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to display progressbar before loading list like following image. my class extended SherlockListFragment with AsyncTask. I goggled lot but not got suitable information for implementing progressbar . can anybody help me how to implement progressbar like following image.

Thanks in advance.
image 1

[image]

following is the my class

```
public class Residential extends SherlockListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle saved) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.residential_list,container, false);
    resListviewId = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    projectList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    new LoadProjects().execute();

    return view;
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

//inner class for network operation
private class LoadProjects extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ListAdapter projAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),
                projectList, R.layout.residential_list_item, 
                new String[] {PROJ_ID,PROJ_NAME}, new int[] 
                        {R.id.projectId,R.id.projectName});
        //updating the UI
        setListAdapter(projAdapter);
    }
}
}
```

Following is the progressbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/projectLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/projectprogressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/projectProgressTxtvw"
        android:text="@string/Loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It may useful to you.

```
public class Residential extends SherlockListFragment 
{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle saved) 
{
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.residential_list,container, false);
resListviewId = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
projectList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

new LoadProjects().execute();

return view;
}
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();

}
private class LoadProjects extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   showLoader("Loading...");
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

           hideLoader();
    ListAdapter projAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getSherlockActivity(),
            projectList, R.layout.residential_list_item, 
            new String[] {PROJ_ID,PROJ_NAME}, new int[] 
                    {R.id.projectId,R.id.projectName});
    //updating the UI
    setListAdapter(projAdapter);
}
}
public void showLoader(final String msg)
{
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{ 
@Override
public void run() 
    {
if(dialog == null)
    dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Theme_Dialog_Translucent);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
ImageView imgeView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgeView);
TextView tvLoading = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvLoading);
if(msg.length() > 0)
    tvLoading.setText(msg);
imgeView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frame);
animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) imgeView.getBackground();
imgeView.post(new Runnable()
{
 @Override
 public void run() 
 {
   if(animationDrawable != null)
    animationDrawable.start();
 }
});
 }
 });
 }
protected void hideLoader()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
}
```

frame.xml:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader1" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader2" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader3" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader4" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader5" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader6" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader7" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader8" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader9" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader10" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader11" android:duration="50"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loader12" android:duration="50"></item>
</animation-list>
```

Loading.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llPopup"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp" >
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgeViews"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvLoading"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="Loading..."
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i will try this but for this loader can i need 10 images and you don't need to write runOnUiThread in showLoader because onPreExecute and onPostExecute already run on uiThread.

Comment: Thanks I know runOnUiTread no need on onPreEx... actually i used this two methods in my BaseActivity class which is common frame for all screen in my project. Pls conform me is it really useful or not. jest you prepare 10 images of cyclic flow other vice search in iconfinder.